# how to get selected options from multiple dropdowns using getAllSelectedOptions

Tags: java, selenium

```
Select dropdown1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div//div//select")));
List<WebElement> drop1 = dropdown1.getAllSelectedOptions();
for(WebElement temp : drop1) {
      String drop_text = temp.getText();
      System.out.println(drop_text);
}
```

The above xpath represents 3 dropdown fields.When i execute this code i am getting the selected text in first dropdown only.What changes i need to do in this to get the selected options from all three dropdown fields.

```
 **html code**

<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type-select">Category<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <select defaultattr="4" class="form-control input-style mandatory" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">Architectural Firm</option>
<option value="2">Interior Design Firm</option>
<option value="3">General Contractor</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">2tec2 Sales Network</option>
<option value="5">Cleaning Company</option>
<option value="6">Commercial end user</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type-select">Company Status</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control input-style" id="ddlCompanyStatus">
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">Active</option>
                    <option value="0">Non Active</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "3 dropdown fields"? Do you mean it's 1 dropdown box, and then there are 3 fields showing selected? Also, please post the HTML of the dropdown box.

Comment: I don't see that the `<select>` allows for multiselection.

Comment: In the above HTML code you can find 3 dropdown boxes and its options listed.I gave executed my code and got the output as "2tec2 Sales Network".But i also need to get selected text in second dropdown box i.e., "Active" following the 3rd dropdown box

Comment: 1. I only see **two** `<select>` fields. 2. `getAllSelectedOptions()` only works for a `<select>` with the `multiple` attribute, which you do not have set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css selector `option:checked` to get selected options

```
List<WebElement> selectedOpts = driver.findElements(
         By.cssSelector("select.form-control > option:checked"));

for(WebElement temp : selectedOpts ) {
      System.out.println(temp.getText());
}
```

Comment: By executing the above code i got the result as 

2tec2 Sales Network,
Active,
Selenium.

In this how can i exclude one option(Suppose i don't want to select 2tec2 Sales Network)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, calling `findElement()` only returns a single element from the HTML page. In order to get all elements that match a given selector, you need to call `findElements()` instead.

Secondly, you seem to be under the impression that `getAllSelectedOptions()` will return all of the options selected for all `<select>` fields. This is not the case. Instead, it only returns all of the selected options for a **single** `<select>` field. This only makes sense if you use the `multiple` attribute.

To get the selected option in each `<select>`, you first need to use `findElements()` instead of `findElement()`. Then you need to iterate over the selected elements and call `getSelectedOption()` on each one.